# Can I have something run constantly on GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, trie

I need to check whether some words(or prefix of words) exist, the best approach is to build a Trie, which however is not easy on GAE, it shall stay in the memory(or i have to build it every time i look up some strings), and I don't know how to implement that on GAE.

The ideal result is, build a Trie when the app launches, keep it as long as the app runs.

I tried to store all the words and prefixes in the big table, which didn't give a good performance.

Comment: How big is the Trie? If it's reasonably sized, you could built it afresh on each instance.

Comment: @NickJohnson some dict i found on the web, about 700k in origin

Comment: In that case, I would just deserialize it on each instance. This will be faster and cheaper than storing it on a backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might consider a backend to hold the data then.

> Backends are special App Engine instances that have no request deadlines, higher memory and CPU limits, and persistent state across requests. They are started automatically by App Engine and can run continously for long periods. Each backend instance has a unique URL to use for requests, and you can load-balance requests across multiple instances.
>
> Backends can handle HTTP requests from users or other parts of your
>   application, start and run continuously in the background, or be
>   driven by Task Queue tasks or Cron jobs. 
>   https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/

Comment: backends does not have free quota, does it?

Comment: it does, but not a full 24 hours per day. it's  9.00 Instance Hours actually. but your question never mentioned "free" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use instance memory to hold the trie and build it with Python objects.

See this article: http://blog.notdot.net/2010/11/Storage-options-on-App-Engine with other options to store the trie.